# Displaying data in wide 2 column table

Tags: tables, data-tables, data-display

So I got myself into a corner and feeling quite stuck with this one, wondering what would other UXDs do. I have a wide table (960px) and only two columns. What's the best way to display it? Thanks
[image]

Comment: If it's always a label and an action, I'd go for what you're showing in your image. The label aligned to the left and the action aligned to the right. Looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks! It's just that it looks kind of awkward to have so much empty space in between. Was wondering, maybe that's not the best way to display such set

Comment: Consider that titles can be very long and users have a smaller screen. It looks empty when you have dummy text there, but it won't be awkward when a users has a 640px screen and a 120 character title. :)

Comment: The thing is my text strings are quite short, it's basically month + year and the action will be something like 'view' or 'edit'

Comment: You might want to make the table less wide and center it on the screen. This would put the whitespace on either side of the table rather than in between the columns.

Comment: So why is this bad?

Comment: The problem is, I have a card based UI and there are other tables on the page with more columns. Shrinking this one table width will disrupt the overall UI. All other tables have actions aligned to max right

Comment: @Majo0od The "problem" with this much spacing (the way it's displayed above) is that sometimes when you go to click on an _Action_ button, it's easy to "lose" which entry you're clicking on.

Comment: @TripeHound not with those lines you wont. Plus there are other ways of making it easier to track to what you're clicking by adding more padding.

Comment: Are you able to actually show a mockup with real data, e.g what instances of Items could be and what the Actions that are possible would be. But as it is, I don't think it's bad visually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that a widely-spaced screen like this can look "odd", although if it's consistent with the rest of the UI this may not be as much of a problem (and for that reason I can somewhat understand your reluctance to alter the layout).

To me, the biggest problem will be that in trying to click one of the **Action** elements, it's too easy to "miss by one" and click on the wrong line.

Part of [Maisa's answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/107437/57088) offers one solution: shading alternate lines will help minimise clicking on the wrong one. However, if you feel doing that would break consistency with other screens/cards, an alternative could be to shade the whole of a row when the mouse hovers over it. That way, as you approach the **Action** button on the right, you'll be able to see easily which item you're about to affect.

(Of course, hovering doesn't work on a phone/tablet. A phone's display is probably narrow enough that the wide-spacing won't be a problem; for a tablet you could make tapping on a row highlight/shade that row which would achieve a similar effect).

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the size of the table according the size of your data to join the information.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOGDnN.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Thank you however, the problem is, I have a card based UI and there are other tables on the page with more columns. Shrinking this one table width will disrupt the overall UI

Comment: Hm that's the problem, so you can align action to left to join the information.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to consider that the "items" might have a longer text. So let's keep that in mind and if users have longer text, then it might look good ;)

Then your action should look like a button (what is it exactly?).

With only 2 columns, that is the best you could do.

If your list is a list of action, you could include a deadline column on the left of the action button/call to action.

Hope that helped.